# Атрибут min HTML

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так что бы значение могло быть любым но не меньше 0.01?

Answer (score 0):

Так вы сами написали, что это атрибут `min` ([webref.ru](https://webref.ru/html/input/min))
`type="number"` - числовое поле
`min` - минимальное значение
`step` - шаг переключения

```html
<input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01">
```